# Shell command pr

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix, tr

How do I edit command pr

```
tr [:upper:] [:lower:] < "${FILE}" | tr -d [:digit:] | sort | pr -s' ' -t3 | nl
```

so that the output looks like this:

```
 1  bcxwhex jbdafn  osnu
 2  bijly   jdofnx  uriqcl
 3  btgr    jz      uztyp
 4  bwifmn  kfaky   wfwdz
 5  bxgvs   kigdo   wgdax
 6  cfukt   lf      wgfil
 7  cgyqlp  lnccknh ypt
 8  eocbm   njevos  zcplnln
 9  hgmbc   ocndbmr znknpo
10  iawmkbh opder   zyezfq
```

and not like this:

```
 1  bcxwhex jbdafn osnu
 2  bijly jdofnx uriqcl
 3  btgr jz uztyp
 4  bwifmn kfaky wfwdz
 5  bxgvs kigdo wgdax
 6  cfukt lf wgfil
 7  cgyqlp lnccknh ypt
 8  eocbm njevos zcplnln
 9  hgmbc ocndbmr znknpo
10  iawmkbh opder zyezfq
```

Comment: Pipe it to `column -t`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `-s ' '` if you don't want the columns to separated by a single space.

As an aside, [don't use upper case for your private variables.](/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace space to tab with tr, before you do nl

```
tr [:upper:] [:lower:] < "${FILE}" | tr -d [:digit:] | sort | pr -s' ' -t3 | tr ' ' \\t| nl
```

And that will tidy up the spaces for you

Comment: This will mess up the formatting if the columns contain spaces in the actual text.